# Spring Security or Database for managing views and authentication of users

Tags: database, spring, spring-mvc, security

I am developing a web app in Spring MVC. I want to ask about solution guide lines for following problem:

1. Users get registered
2. Each user has different level of access levels and also some users have completely different level of form to work with.

I want to make the view appropriate to user login. He only see that form of views that are authorized to him and We can set the user access level of different views from admin panel.

Should i use database tables for controlling this.?

Answer (score 0):

You must implement a part that manage user authentification and access for this i recommend you to use the framework Spring security.
Here is some documentation and exemple that can help you :
http://websystique.com/spring-security-tutorial/